# Returning sum of column using Room in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dao

I am new to Android and Kotlin so I need help.
This is my data class:

```
@Entity
data class Insurance(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val uid: Int,
var date: String,
var msisdn: String,
var category: String,
var hitno: String,
var priceOfInsurance: Int
) {
override fun toString(): String {
    return "Insurance(date=$date - msisdn$msisdn - category=$category - hitno1=$hitno " +
            "- priceOfInsurance=$priceOfInsurance )"
}
```

and these are my queries:

```
@Dao
interface InsuranceDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Insurance")
fun fetchAll(): LiveData<List<Insurance>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(arg: Insurance)

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun update(arg: Insurance)

@Delete
suspend fun delete(arg: Insurance)

@Query("DELETE FROM Insurance")
fun deleteAllInsurance()

}
```

My question is how do I make a query that can sum the colon priceOfInsurance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
const val tablename = “your table name”
const val column = “your column name”

const val QUERY =“select sum( $column ) from $tablename”

@Query(QUERY)
fun getSum(): Int
```